# stomp.js cannot receive message sent from pika (RabbitMQ version: 3.11.7)

Tags: rabbitmq, stomp, pika, rabbitmq-exchange, python-pika

I have a web page that should receive messages from RabbitMQ using STOMP:

```
<body>
    <script src="stomp.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sockjs-client@1.1/dist/sockjs.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var client = Stomp.client('ws://localhost:15674/ws');

        client.debug = null;
        var sub = function(d) {
            // print_first(d.body);
            console.log("got the message! ", d.body)
        }
        var on_connect = function(x) {
            id = client.subscribe("/topic/test", sub);
            console.log("connected")
        };
        var on_error =  function() {
          console.log('error');
        };
        
        client.connect('guest', 'guest', on_connect, on_error, '/');
    </script>
</body>
```

when I run this code, it shows `connected` in the console (so far so good)

I also have a python backend, which should send messages to the queue (send.py):

```py
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare("/topic/test")

properties = pika.BasicProperties(
        content_type='application/json',
        content_encoding='utf-8',
        delivery_mode=2,
    )

channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='/topic/test',
                      body='Hello World!',
                      properties=properties)
```

The messages are sent (I ran the script with `py -m send`; the messages appear in the RabbitMQ Management) :
[image: the UI for rabbitMQ]

However the `console.log` in `sub` isn't running. Any idea how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello! I maintain Pika and am on the RabbitMQ engineering team. Could you please provide a git repository I can clone to reproduce this issue? Without using the *exact* same code as you I would just be guessing at what the issue is. Thank you.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering, I was using the official Docker image. In the end I was able to solve the issue by using stomp.py instead of pika, I will probably post an answer here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using stomp.py instead of pika:

```
import stomp
PORT = 61613
LOCALHOST = '0.0.0.0'
conn = stomp.Connection11([(LOCALHOST, PORT)])  
conn.connect('guest','guest')
conn.send(body="start",destination='/queue/test')
conn.send(body="end",destination='/queue/test')
conn.disconnect()
```